# How to define the Bernstein function like the built-in BernsteinBasis?

Tags: programming, built-in-symbols

We know the ***Bernstein*** function defined as below:

$$B_{n,i}(u)=\binom n i u^i(1-u)^{n-i}$$

And we define $B_{n,i}(u)=0$ when $i<0 $ or $i>n$

In addition, the first derivative of $B_{n,i}(u)$ has the below relationship:

$$B'_{n,i}(u)=n\left[B_{n-1,i-1}(u)-B_{n-1,i}(u)\right]$$

So I can utilize this equation to calculate the derivative of order $k$

$$B^{(k)}_{n,i}(u)=n(n-1)\cdots (n-k+1)\\ 
 \left[\{B_{n-k,i-k}(u),\cdots,B_{n-k,i}(u)\} .coefficient\right]$$

Here,$coefficient$ has the style (1,-3,3,1),(1, -4, 6, -4, 1),etc

#### Implementation

```
Bernstein[n_, i_, u_] /; i < 0 || i > n := 0
Bernstein[0, 0, u_] := 1
Bernstein[n_, i_, u_?NumericQ] := Binomial[n, i] u^i (1 - u)^(n - i)
```

**The derivative of *Bernstein***

```
D[Bernstein[n_, i_, u_], {u_, k_}] ^:=
 Module[{coeff, body},
  coeff = Times @@ Array[n - # &, k, 0];
  body =
   Array[Bernstein[n - k, #, u] &, k + 1, i - k].
    CoefficientList[(1 - u)^k, u];
  coeff* body
]
(*=======================================*)
D[Bernstein[n_, i_, u_], u_] ^:= D[Bernstein[n, i, u], {u, 1}]
```

However, the *Mathematica* give me the warining information

> [image]

**Expand the expression**

```
PiecewiseExpand[expr_] ^:=
 expr /. Bernstein[n_, i_, u_Symbol] :> 
  Binomial[n, i] u^i (1 - u)^(n - i)
```

> [image]

---

#### Tesing

**Successful case**

```
Bernstein[3, 2, .4](*0.288*)

D[Bernstein[3, 2, u], u]
```

> ```
> 3 (Bernstein[2, 1, u] - Bernstein[2, 2, u])
> ```

```
D[Bernstein[3, 2, u], {u, 2}]
```

> ```
> 6 (Bernstein[1, 0, u] - 2 Bernstein[1, 1, u])
> ```

**Failture**

```
D[Bernstein[3, 2, u], u] // PiecewiseExpand
```

> no expantion >_<

#### Question

- How to fix the warining information about `UpSetDelayed`?
- Is it possible to implement the derivative of $B_{n,i}(u)$ by *rule-based* solution? I have a trial, but failed.

---

**My trial**

```
D[Berns[n_, i_, u_], {u_, k_}] ^:=
 Do[
  Bernstein[n, i, u] /.
   Bernstein[x_, y_, z_] :> 
    x (Bernstein[x - 1, y - 1, u] - Bernstein[x - 1, y, z]), {k}]
 (*failture*)
```

***Built-in function***

```
D[BernsteinBasis[6, 3, u], {u, 3}]
```

> [image]

Obviously, the *Mathematica* utilizes a recursive method by observing the result.

Answer (score 5):

Your use of `UpSetDelayed` had issues. The first problem is that it couldn't deal with the pattern corresponding to the differentiation variable and order in defining the derivative. Later, when defining the action of `PiecewiseExpand`, `UpSetDelayed` cannot work at all because it needs to be associated with `BernsteinBasis` (or some *symbol*) and not with the *placeholder* for an expression, given by the *pattern* `expr_`.

To fix the first issue, I would suggest not using `UpSetDelayed` at all and instead doing it this way:

```
Bernstein[n_, i_, u_] /; i < 0 || i > n := 0
Bernstein[0, 0, u_] := 1
Bernstein[n_, i_, u_?NumericQ] := Binomial[n, i] u^i (1 - u)^(n - i)

Bernstein[3, 2, .4]

(* ==> 0.288 *)

Derivative[0, 0, k_][Bernstein][n_, i_, u_] := 
 Module[{coeff, body}, coeff = Times @@ Array[n - # &, k, 0];
  body = Array[Bernstein[n - k, #, u] &, k + 1, 
     i - k].CoefficientList[(1 - u)^k, u];
  coeff*body]

D[Bernstein[3, 2, u], u]

(* ==> 3 (Bernstein[2, 1, u] - Bernstein[2, 2, u]) *)

D[Bernstein[3, 2, u], {u, 2}]

(*
==> 3 (2 (Bernstein[1, 0, u] - Bernstein[1, 1, u]) - 
   2 Bernstein[1, 1, u])
*)

Simplify[%]

(* ==> 6 (Bernstein[1, 0, u] - 2 Bernstein[1, 1, u]) *)

bernsteinExpand = 
  Bernstein[n_, i_, u_Symbol] :> Binomial[n, i] u^i (1 - u)^(n - i);

D[Bernstein[3, 2, u], u] /. bernsteinExpand

(* ==> 3 (2 (1 - u) u - u^2) *)
```

Here I made the definition for `Derivative` with `SetDelayed`. This form is always arrived at when you try to do derivatives even with `D`, so there is no need for the second definition for the first derivative that you had in your approach.

The tests seem to work as expected. For the `PieceWiseExpand`, I couldn't see a reason why it should be used at all, and instead I defined a rule to make the desired replacement by appending `/.bernsteinExpand` to any given expression. I think if you want to give definitions for `PiecewiseExpand`, you'll have to `Unprotect` it first, and I didn't want to do that.

**Edit in response to comment**

In the tests, I used the `D` operator instead of `Derivative`. The form involving `D` is ultimately transformed into `Derivative`, and not *vice versa*. That's why it's more general to make definitions for `Derivative` than for `D`. However, when you test higher-order derivatives with `D`, then *Mathematica* executes them as repeated first-order derivatives. This can be seen using `Trace`:

```
Trace[D[f[x], {x, 2}]]
```

> $\left\{\frac{\partial ^2f(x)}{\partial
>    x^2},\left(f'\right)'(x),\left\{\left(f'\right)',f''
>    \right\},f''(x)\right\}$

For your application, this means that the call

```
D[Bernstein[3, 2, u], {u, 2}]
```

is broken up into two steps, tantamount to

```
D[Bernstein[3, 2, u], u]
```

followed by

```
D[%, u]
```

And as you can see by doing these two steps, this means that the definition for `Derivative` with `k > 1` is not used. That's why I had to `Simplify` the result. Instead, if you ask for the `Derivative` in the more formal way, you get the direct route:

```
Derivative[0, 0, 2][Bernstein][3, 2, u]

6 (Bernstein[1, 0, u] - 2 Bernstein[1, 1, u])
```

This is the result you wanted. If you care about a more concise notation, you could modify all the above definitions so that `Bernstein[n_,i_,u_]` is replaced by `Bernstein[n_,i_][u_]`. Then you can type the derivatives as `Bernstein[n,i]'[u]`, `Bernstein[n,i]''[u]` etc.

---

**Simplify** the code of the derivative of *Bernstein* basis

```
Derivative[0, 0, 1][Bernstein] := 
 Function[{deg, idx, u}, 
  Piecewise[ 
   {{deg Bernstein[deg - 1, idx - 1, u], deg == idx}, 
    {-deg Bernstein[deg - 1, idx, u], idx == 0}}, 
    deg (Bernstein[deg - 1, idx - 1, u] - Bernstein[deg - 1, idx, u])] 
 ];
```

Comment: +1, Thanks a lot. However, I have a question. Why `D[Bernstein[3, 2, u], {u, 2}]` gives the result `3 (2 (Bernstein[1, 0, u] - Bernstein[1, 1, u]) - 
   2 Bernstein[1, 1, u])`, rather than `6 (Bernstein[1, 0, u] - 2 Bernstein[1, 1, u])`. Because in the function, I write down the latter style directly (`coeff*body`)

Comment: @ShutaoTang I don't understand why you edited my answer. The added definition doesn't seem to have anything to do with what I said.

Comment: sorry, @Jens maybe I should add the defintion in the bottom.

Comment: @Shutao, I'm clearly missing the point of the explicit `Piecewise[]` as they are supposed to be implicit in the definition for the Bernstein functions. I don't have time to look at this in detail right now, but I did give you the correct general formula. You only have to specialize it to the first derivative case.

Comment: @J. M. Yes, the formula you give me is right, namely,　$$B^{(k)}_{n,i}(u)=n(n-1)\cdots (n-k+1)\\ 
 \left[\{B_{n-k,i-k}(u),\cdots,B_{n-k,i}(u)\} .coeffs\right]$$　Here,`coeffs`　has the style like`(1,-3,3,1),(1, -4, 6, -4, 1)` ,etc．