# Checking the argument of user-defined function with side-effect method

Tags: programming, message-coding, argument-patterns, side-effect

Today, I answered a question of mine that asked two month ago. Please see [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/79271/how-to-define-the-bernstein-function-like-the-built-in-bernsteinbasis/88851#88851)

Now I would like to add the **argument checking** in this function. Then I used a method that [Mr.Wizard answered](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/85821/how-to-check-the-style-and-number-of-arguments-like-the-built-in-functions/86604#86604)

#### Requirement for the arguments of `Bernstein[n,i,u]`

- `n` must be a integer like $1,2,3,...$;
- `i` must be a integer like $1,2,3,...$;
- `i` should between `0` and `n-1`.

For instance, the *built-in* `BernsteinBasis` gives the warning information as below:

```
BernsteinBasis[1.2, 2, 3]
```

> BernsteinBasis::intnm: Non-negative machine-sized integer expected at position 1 in BernsteinBasis[1.2,2,3]. >>

```
BernsteinBasis[1.2, 2.1, 3]
```

> BernsteinBasis::intnm: Non-negative machine-sized integer expected at position 1 in BernsteinBasis[1.2,2.1,3]. >>
>
> BernsteinBasis::intnm: Non-negative machine-sized integer expected at position 2 in BernsteinBasis[1.2,2.1,3]. >>

```
BernsteinBasis[4, 5, u]
```

> BernsteinBasis::invidx2:Index 5 should be a machine-sized integer 
>   between 0 and 4. >>

#### checkArgs

```
Attributes[checkArgs] = {HoldAll};
(*check the number of arguments*)
checkArgs [func_[args___]] /; Length@{args} != 3 := 
  Message[func::argrx, func, Length@{args}, 3]

(*check the type of the first arguments*)
checkArgs [func_[a_, b_, c_]] /; ! MatchQ[a, _Integer?NonNegative] := 
  Message[func::intnm, func[a, b, c], 1]

(*check the type of second arguments*)
checkArgs [func_[a_, b_, c_]] /; ! MatchQ[b, _Integer?NonNegative] := 
  Message[func::intnm, func[a, b, c], 2]

checkArgs[func_[a_, b_, c_]] /; ! (0 <= b <= a - 1) := 
  Message[func::invidx, b, 0, a - 1]

(*other valid cases*)
checkArgs[other_] := True
```

#### Main implementation

```
Bernstein::invidx = 
 "The index `1` should be a non-negative machine-sized integer betwwen `2` and `3`.";

 SetAttributes[Bernstein, {Listable, NHoldAll, NumericFunction}]
(*special cases*)

Bernstein[n_, i_, u_]?checkArgs /; i < 0 || i > n := 0

Bernstein[0, 0, u_]?checkArgs := 1

Bernstein[n_, i_, u_?NumericQ]?checkArgs := 
 Binomial[n, i] u^i (1 - u)^(n - i)

(*expansion of the basis of Bernstein*)
Bernstein /: PiecewiseExpand[Bernstein[n_, i_, u_]] := 
 Piecewise[
  {{Binomial[n, i] u^i (1 - u)^(n - i), 0 <= u <= 1}, 
   {0, u > 1 || u < 0}}]

(*the derivatives of the basis of Bernstein*)
Bernstein /: Derivative[0, 0, k_Integer?Positive][Bernstein] := 
 Function[{n, i, u}, 
  D[
   n (Bernstein[n - 1, i - 1, u] - Bernstein[n - 1, i, u]), 
   {u, k - 1}]
 ]
```

However, it gives the following information.

> $RecursionLimit::reclim: Recursion depth of 256 exceeded. >>
>
> $RecursionLimit::reclim: Recursion depth of 256 exceeded. >>
>
> $RecursionLimit::reclim: Recursion depth of 256 exceeded. >>
>
> General::stop: Further output of $RecursionLimit::reclim will be suppressed during this calculation. >>
>
> Bernstein::intnm: Non-negative machine-sized integer expected at position >Bernstein[n_,i_,u_] in 1. >>

---

#### Update

Thanks for *Mr.Wizard's* revision that adding `HoldForm` in `checkArgs` to remove the *recursion*.

In addition, *Mr.Wizard* given me a hint that ultilizing the **Message** as a **side-effect** in the [comment](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/88861/checking-the-argument-of-user-defined-function-bernstein/88937?noredirect=1#comment242690_88937)

Now I have a reference [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/23345/how-to-program-a-fargx-message/23356#23356)

```
SyntaxInformation[f] = {"ArgumentsPattern" -> {_}};
f[1] := True
f[_] := False
f[x___] /; Message[f::argx, "f", Length@{x}] := Null
```

Additional, The Toad has a [comment](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/23345/how-to-program-a-fargx-message/23356#comment72722_23356) as below:

> I just remembered why I don't use this in my packages... if you have *different messages* being thrown based on the form of the input (as I often have), then throwing messages as a *side-effect* of *not* **matching the form** will result in all messages being thrown

However, this demo just for one argument, and when the number of argument greater than $1$, I have any idea to deal with **Message** with side-effect.

Comment: @SjoerdC.deVries, I know the built-in `BernsteinBasis` applied the `UpValues` method. For instance, `D[BernsteinBasis[5, 3, u], {u, 2}]`. In addition, `BernsteinBasis[3., 1., u]` gives the warning information normally.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard, In this case, I used your "Fall-through method " , however, it failed. Could you help me if you have time?

Comment: @ShutaoTang `@name` notifications *only* work of a user has already commented on the post therefore I did not see your notice.  However I saw this now due to the recent edit.  If I have time today I shall attempt to answer this.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard, Thanks a lot.:-) Now I am trying to apply [your methods](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/85821/how-to-check-the-style-and-number-of-arguments-like-the-built-in-functions/86604#86604) that hand error-message in my functions. However, this time I failed and I didn't why.

Answer (score 4):

I have given your code only a cursory read but I think I spotted a (the?) problem: your `Message` code uses an unheld equivalent of the test expression itself.  This cannot work.  If the expression would generate a `Message` the first time it would even *within* `Message` and you will get infinite recursion.  Use `HoldForm` to prevent this:

```
(*check the type of the first arguments*)
checkArgs[self : func_[a_, b_, c_]] /; ! MatchQ[a, _Integer?NonNegative] := 
 Message[func::intnm, HoldForm[self], 1]

(*check the type of second arguments*)
checkArgs[self : func_[a_, b_, c_]] /; ! MatchQ[b, _Integer?NonNegative] := 
 Message[func::intnm, HoldForm[self], 2]
```

With this correction your code no longer produces a recursion error on definition, however I get:

> Bernstein::intnm: Non-negative machine-sized integer expected at position 1 in Bernstein[n_,i_,u_]. >>

I *believe* this comes from the limited evaluation that takes place during function definition and I *think* the definition will still be made correctly, but I'll have to check that later.

Separately I think you can and probably should be including `checkArgs` in the TagSet definition:

```
Bernstein /: PiecewiseExpand[Bernstein[n_, i_, u_]?checkArgs] := . . .
```

However again I haven't made an attempt to test this definition itself.  If you have additional problems please note them in the question and I shall try to help when I return to this.

Comment: +1,THX, Now I utilize the followng cases: `Bernstein[3.2, 1, u]` ,`Bernstein[3, 1.2, u]` and `Bernstein[5, 6, u]` to test the funtion `Bernstein` and then they give the desired error informtion respectively. However, I would like to how inplement the `checkArg` to make the `Bernstein[3.2, 1.2, u]` return two error-message like `BernsteinBasis[3.2, 1.2, u]`

Comment: @Shutao If you want more than one error message you can issue the `Message` as a side-effect rather than a match on `checkArgs`.  The evaluator would then try all of the checks rather that stopping after the first `Message`.  However if you want all messages to fire I think it is actually better or at least easier to make the definition upon the primary function (`Bernstein`).  The methods I described were posted in response to [the implied desire *not* to issue multiple messages.](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/23345/how-to-program-a-fargx-message/23356#comment72722_23356)

Comment: The Toad's comment: `throwing messages as a side-effect of not matching the form will result in all messages being thrown`. But , for me, I don't know how to implement this(**throwing messages as a side-effect**). So could you give me a demo by this `Bernstein` case? ThX!

Comment: @Shutao FYI I am not ignoring you; I've just got other things to work on too.